The measurability of a process.
Consider a process ${(X_t)}_{t\in[0,T]}$ and a constant $m\in\mathbb{R}$. The Snell envelope of the process $X\vee m$ is given by
\begin{equation}
Z_t(m)=\text{esssup}_{\tau\in\mathfrak{T}(t,T)}\mathbb{E}\left[Z_\tau\vee m|\mathcal{F}_t\right]
\end{equation}
where $\mathfrak{T}(t,T)$ is the family of stopping times with values in $[t,T]$. My question is: the following process is adapted?
\begin{equation}
L_t=\sup\{m\in\mathbb{Q}| Z_t(m)=Z_t\}
\end{equation}
I think it is not, because the value where the supremum of $m$ is attained depends of the futures times in $[0,T]$. But I am not sure how to explain it in a formal way. Any suggestion or help is welcome. Thanks!.
